# Webpack - loggin and analysing

Tags: javascript, webpack

I made some search around google to find out how to see the log of what is happening into the webpack process of building. But i didnt find anything, may be because its easy and i am not a expert in Nodejs/webpack.

Somebody has a tip on how can i deal with that so i can move on some errors that come from lack of practice on this subject (or even hard ones)?  For example, i had a problem that i put cotes into the regex for the modules/rules/test , i didn't saw any error happening that could lead to a solution (perhaps a log message informing that the test regex didn't match anything ?), so i got stuck into that for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically putting quotes on a regex is correct, but the expected result will not be correct. Most of the things that goes wrong with webpack has an error message and it is going to tell you what is wrong.
If you want to debug deeper, you could use the [debugger](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) functionality that node has to "debug" the webpack code.

Comment: But isnt there a way to get logs ? only debugging i will have some info of the proces?

Comment: No way to get logs. The only logs you get are the one popping on the screen. Debugging you'll see how it works internally